# Python sendto() not working on 3.1 (works on 2.6)

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, udp, sendto

For some reason, the following seems to work perfectly on my ubuntu machine running python 2.6 and returns an error on my windows xp box running python 3.1

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
data = 'UDP Test Data'
port = 12345
hostname = '192.168.0.1'
udp = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
udp.sendto(data, (hostname, port))
```

Below is the error that the python 3.1 throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sendto.py", line 6, in <module>
    udp.sendto(data, (hostname, port))
TypeError: sendto() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

I have consulted the documentation for python 3.1 and the sendto() only requires two parameters. Any ideas as to what may be causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 3, the string (first) argument must be of type bytes or buffer, not str.  You'll get that error message if you supply the optional flags parameter.  Change data to:

d`ata = b'UDP Test Data'`

You might want to file a bug report about that at the python.org bug tracker.  [EDIT: already filed as noted by Dav]

...

```
>>> data = 'UDP Test Data'
>>> udp.sendto(data, (hostname, port))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sendto() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
>>> udp.sendto(data, 0, (hostname, port))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sendto() argument 1 must be bytes or buffer, not str
>>> data = b'UDP Test Data'
>>> udp.sendto(data, 0, (hostname, port))
13
>>> udp.sendto(data, (hostname, port))
13
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I should have followed your approach and picked up that it expects datatypes of either bytes or buffer. Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Related issue on the Python bugtracker:
http://bugs.python.org/issue5421

Comment: Thanks! The explanation on the bugtracker didnt make much sense initially, but i now understand that it requires either a datatype of byte or buffer.